# Storing a Fractional Twitter Firehose with MongoDB on EC2

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, bigdata, nosql

I am looking to satisfy the following requirements:

1. Store lots and lots of tweets (say 5 million a day) and associated user profiles.
2. Be able to query the data (get me all tweets created between time X and time Y).
3. Be able to add servers to the cluster as the data size increases.

I am unfamiliar with MongoDB.

A. Can I satisfy the above with MongoDB?

B. If I were to do the above using EC2, what specification of Hardware would you recommend:
  For example: Start with 2 Large Instances with 500GB of EBS attached to each.

Thanks.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to build a test system and benchmark it and match it against your other unspecified use cases. There is likely a way to get any modern DB system to support your needs as they've been described.

Comment: Did I not just comment on a more broad version of this? Anyway I agree you need to do more research and testing before posting. I mean you have this scenario and you are asking about a tech that you are not familiar with. You need to research a bit more

Comment: @Sammaye, I took your points into consideration and I deleted that question and narrowed it down to something that I think is more tractable. And, if someone asked me the same question for say MySQL I would be able to answer it for them and I would gladly do so. I am doing more research but I thought getting access to people who've tread the path before me is the whole point of this site.

Comment: @WPCoder, I am building actually building a synthetic tweet generator for this purpose. However for example if someone asked me if I could do the above with MySQL I would advise them to look elsewhere.

Comment: Well your question atm is lacking true research, you have not tried anything yourself. We cannot reliably give server recommendations since the server type depends upon your queries and working set and index. So really I can only answer a which is a yes but then this is a yes for 99% of databases out there. So your question lacks research in its current context and fails to describe a true problem.

Comment: @user1172468 I'd challenge you on why MySQL wouldn't work for this scenario, as you haven't given enough context to provide an answer. In fact, a series of flat files with a simple index would work given the details you've provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Really your question lacks any real research your end as such it is unclear and off topic a little, however I will give some pointers on the topic; maybe they will help you out.

Yes, MongoDB just like MySQL or MSSQL or Postgres SQL could handle this workload. This dataset is nothing new to databases. Yes I suppose if you were storing 9,000 tweets a second and 500 million odd a day ( http://yearinreview.twitter.com/en/tps.html ) you might want to look into your choice of technology very carefully (as Twitter did when they chose to go the NoSQL route) but you are storing much much less than that. However even in this scenario it has been proven that with the right set-up (Facebook here) MySQL can also handle loads like that.

So this isn't a question of: *can this database handle this?* it is more of a question of: *how can my database handle this?*

First thing I would mention is to do more research into how server clusters are built in MongoDB, I can safely say that if you need replicas ( http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/replication/ ) and shards ( http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/sharding/ ) you will need more than two servers.

If you really want my personal opinion on this I chose not to go for the more resource heavy servers such as large instances and decided to go for the smaller servers in much higher number. They prove cheaper and actually easier to manage in the long run.

Now talking about how a database can handle this again. I have introduced sharding and replica sets. These two parts will be extremely important to you to keep your database scaling well into a cluster and to keep consistency and availability of your data but this is only one part. You must also have the right working set and the right indexes and the right schema (a lot of rights there, not an English mistake - intentional).

I can imagine you will have two collections for this, a `user` collection and a `tweet` collection with maybe indexes on `_id` for a user and `user_id` for `tweet`. You will probably make those into shard keys as well splitting the `tweet` collection on `user_id` so you can quickly range a users tweets across multiple computers by only querying one computer instead of doing a global scatter and gather operation. However considering you might have to do time operations too (get tweets between x and y date) you might want to look into some time based shard index instead, I am unsure; this is for your testing.

That should get you started on thinking and researching into MongoDB for your use case.

Hope it helps,